# Комментарии в блоге

Tags: python-3.x, django

**Views.py**

```
def blogpost(request, id):
    if NewsBlog.objects.all():
        post = get_object_or_404(NewsBlog, id=id)
    comments = BlogComments.objects.filter(post=post)
    lastnews = NewsBlog.objects.all().order_by('newsdate')[::-1][:3]

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        cuser = request.user
        cUser = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, id=cuser.id)
        form = BlogComment()
        form.commentator = request.user
        form.post = post
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = BlogComment(request.POST)

    return render(request, 'blog-post.html', locals())
```

**models.py**

```
class BlogComments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(NewsBlog)
    commdate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    commentator = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Показывать')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s комментировал %s' % (self.commentator, self.post)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Комментарий'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Комментарии'
```

Как сделать чтобы комментарии сохранялись от имени текущего пользователя и привязывались к текущему посту?

Comment: В `request.user` лежит текущий пользователь, а дальше делайте с ним что хотите, в `BlogComments` пихайте например

Comment: Про то, как сохранить форму, всё есть в официальной документации Django

Comment: Не понимаю. Сейчас я могу выбрать сам в какой пост и от какого пользователя я сохраняю коммент. А как сделать чтоб автоматом ставились текущие значения? Напишите плиз пример?

Comment: Совсем запутался, плиз дайте пример? как воткнуть в form.commentator текущего юзера? и в form.post текущий id поста?

Answer (score 0):

```
      if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BlogComment(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.commentator = cUser
            comment.post = post
            comment.comment = cd['comment']
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('blog/')
```